# How can we show that the limit of the following surface integral is finite?

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, vectors, surface-integrals

I have an arbitrary parameterized surface $S(u,v)$ in Cartesian coordinates **(with finite area)** and the surface passes through origin. There is a very small circular hole of radius $\epsilon$ at the origin.

Is there a way to show that the limit of the following surface integral is finite?
$$ \displaystyle \vec{V} = \lim \limits_{\epsilon \to 0} \iint_S \dfrac{dS}{r^2} \hat{r}$$
Here $r$ is the distance between origin and points on our parameterized surface $S(u,v)$. $\hat {r}$ is a unit vector from our surface to origin.

Comment: What is $\hat{r}$?

Comment: $\hat {r}$ is a unit vector from our surface to origin.